# working with tableView, how to build an application to correctly display information

Tags: java, javafx

I understand that the question turned out to be huge, but otherwise it will not be clear to everyone.

I am writing a document manager application for myself, what is happening to me there now - I use the ObservableList collection (located in the main Main class) that operates on variables from the MainData class (it turns out that each instance of this class is a new row in the table). I display all the information through the controller class, that is, I have the first table, where I display all my documents (works), depending on the selected document, I display the necessary information in the corresponding labels (works), but I also there is a second table (it does not work correctly), where, according to my logic, depending on the selected document, I display file names that relate to the selected document (i.e., if one document is highlighted, the second table can display 3 files, and if you select another document, 5 files can be displayed). To check the functionality, I add a couple of rows to the SimpleListProperty collection (which is located in MainData respectively) to display them to the table, but at least my added data in the designer is displayed in the table, they all go in one line, and besides the second table creates the same number of rows as in the first (three identical rows are created in qwerty, asdfgh, since I have three documents created), how to get rid of this dependency? Those. I want to bring my application to the logic that I described above.

Class of all variables

```
public class MainData {
    private final StringProperty numberContract;
    private final ListProperty<String> nameFiles; //here I put the names of the files that relate to the document
    // further variables for Label


    public MainData(String numberContract) {
        this.numberContract = new SimpleStringProperty(numberContract);
        this.nameFiles  = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
        this.nameFiles.add("qwerty");
        this.nameFiles.add("asdfgh"); //i want to add only two rows to the second table
    }
//Further, all getters and setters
```

Class-controller

```
public class MainController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<MainData> contractTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, String> numberContractColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableView<MainData> filesTable;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<MainData, ObservableList<String>> nameFilesColumn;
//далее снова все для Label

// Link to main application.
    private Main main;

 public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;

        // Adding to the table data from the observed list
        contractTable.setItems(main.getContractData());
        filesTable.setItems(main.getContractData());
    }

@FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Initialize the table.
        numberContractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().numberContractProperty());
        nameFilesColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getNameFiles());

         // Listen to the selection changes, and when changing, display
         // additional information about the addressee.
        contractTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> showContractDetails(newValue));
```

Main class

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage menuBar;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;

    /**
     * Data, in the form of an observable list of documents.
     */
    private ObservableList<MainData> contractData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    /**
     * Returns data in the form of an observable list of documents.
     * @return
     */
    public ObservableList<MainData> getContractData() {
        return contractData;
    }
//further FXML display
```

Comment: full code - https://github.com/Zherikhov/docManager

Comment: Why are you using `MainData` as item type for both `TableView`s? Your description indicates that you want to display one `String` per row in the second `TableView` making `String` the appropriate type parameter for `TableView`. You can also update the items in the `showContactDetails` method. Furthermore since you only display a single column per `TableView`, Changing to `ListView` may be an option...

Comment: You could probably simplify things by using a `ListView` as the second table since it's only a list of strings.

Comment: @fabian I use MainData for both tableViews, but in the initialization method I pass the data I need to the table, I thought it would give me the desired result. And I pokozal in the second table, one column, because I thought it would be easier to deal with the code, in fact there are 2 columns

Comment: @fabian How I would like to add data to the second table, if now the collection I use for this lies in `MainData`, as well as the variables for the first table. Do I need to be divided into different classes?

Comment: Does that mean you want to display one column filled with the same value over and over again? (With the info provided it's impossible to make a recommendation here.) Usually you'd so something like `secondTable.setItems(selectedItem.getNameFiles());`.

Comment: @fabian I want to display different information, I will try to show it in this way (Table 1 on the left, Table 2 on the right)
`document1 -> element1, element2`
`document2 -> element3, element4, element5`
each item from a new line

Comment: @fabian probably this is arrogance on my part, but you really help me out if you look at my Git, and better understand the situation, it seems to me that it will not take you much time, because you already understood almost everything. I don't know what to do anymore (

Comment: @fabian if I'm lucky and you decide to download the git, I attached a xml file to simplify, no need to create documents, just upload it